# V for Vendetta - Who am I?

Tags: word, cipher, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

> This link [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=who+am+i) shows how many "Who am I?" riddles we already have on this site. Obviously, there are many of them and they're mostly riddles describing an object in some funny way. On checking the riddles, I noticed how similar they are most of the time. Even though some people here seem to dislike them, I spared no efforts and had a closer look. After reading through some of the questions I ended up asking myself: Seriously, did we ever have a *real* "Who am I?" puzzle? Yeah, so here we go!

---

### Who am I?

[image: Hi, my name is... oooh that was close!]

I left clues here and there but they may seem hard to find. To make things a little easier I'm telling you how many clues there are. Find the hints below to get further information on each of the following clues:

1. Visual 1
2. Words and letters 1
3. Visual 2
4. Words and letters 2
5. Cipher

   ```
   To check your answer you can decypher the message below. As key use my ID:

   "ai qp hczb emzuk dwu ffm uqytok zig vmsh kmc fml or al elff bkq ykwgyt lp lwz 
   vng ltrn dfz dlow lthlq ls syw xabd kwi eudxs
   mcys przh jgmui jvrq bax ycdm wmg tq lz wyg mvt"
   ```

---

### Happy puzzling!

General Notes:

The clues have not been sorted in any way. They can be solved in any order.

The more items you cover with your answer, the higher your chances to win this challenge.

Mods can post answers but not use any fancy mod tools for their investigations.

<strike>If, by any chance, you already know me, I'm kindly asking you to refrain from this for now.</strike> Ask "the guy with the girls" for help.

#### Hints:

1. > Can you read faces?
2. > Try to restore order where something looks shockingly obscene.
3. > My true self looks like a full-grown stino.
4. > All is me thus I'm the beginning of all. Think bigger than this puzzle.
5. > If you're using a key to decipher the message below, make sure to replace numbers with letters from the alphabet. Let 0 become " "(space) and A(1) ... Z(26). For the last part it might be easier to solve one of the other 4 clues first.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### The final message -

> **Well done seems like you have got me in the end**

**The Cipher**

> Using **myid** as key we get -
>
>  *"ok im very sorry for the really bad joke you can go on with the actual id now jpy ihtf atb vicy dqvni ig uqt lcta yya bifpp aeqp dtre xierw lnoe dsu mevj koy qe nr tmi esh"*
>
>
>  Now, using the alphabets as numbers for the ID(32368) which is OP's user id (https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32368/incesterror21) we get - **CBCFH**. Using this as key -
>
>  *how dare you that would be too easy try again zcli bspz qgdpr elnc yls lcqc inw lx lq rhb crf*
>
>  May be the next part needs another key..
>  The picture is clearly of Anonymous!

**Hint 1**

> Can you read faces -
>
>  [@usernameiwantedwasalreadytaken](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52043/30887) found that the Hex value in OP's profile picture's tongue(face) is #510600 and apparently the value corresponds to user id of [Avigrail](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5106/avigrail)

**Hint 2**

> Try to restore order where something looks shockingly obscene.
>
>  [@usernameiwantedwasalreadytaken](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52043/30887) found the anagram RESURRECTION. The username incesterror looks like an obscene word. And the anagram after converting 21 to U is RESURRECTION.

**Hint 3**

> My true self looks like a full-grown stino.
>
>  Avigrail's profile picture link says https://i.stack.imgur.com/STINO.png
>  which is capitalized **STINO**    (Credits @M Oehm)

**Hint 4**

> All is me thus I'm the beginning of all. Think bigger than this puzzle.
>
>  [@Eric](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52113/30887) found that - Taking the first letters of all the posts of OP, we get - 
>  I, G(Chi), R(are), V, A, I, L, A and anagram of this is again - **AVIGRAIL**

**Hint 5**

> With OP's help - if we try to apply the key "ea f" (Avigrail's user ID - 5106) again to cipher "jpy ihtf atb vicy dqvni ig uqt lcta yya bifpp aeqp dtre xierw lnoe dsu mevj koy qe nr tmi esh" - we get - *fpt ehob aox vdyy ymvie ib qqo hcow ytw bdbpk well done seems like you have got me in the end*
>
>  Hence the complete plain text -
>
>  **Well done seems like you have got me in the end**

Comment: But 6 is F, not E, which explains the letters that are off by one.

Comment: The picture is from a movie called 'V for Vendetta' (I think, considering the title) - Anonymous adopted a similar mask but this may not be one of their pictures. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0434409/

Comment: Did you notice the image description in the post source says `Hi, my name is... oooh that was close! `.

Comment: Yeah. Saw it already.. May be a morse code. Not sure. Will check tommorow if its not solved

Comment: Following hint 4 and taking the first letter of each sentence of the quotation forms the word: TOOEASY

Comment: @usernameiwantedwasalreadytaken I think that's just a herring. Tried that as a key but didn't help

Comment: @Techidiot Yeah, tried that too...

Comment: I was looking through the revisions of the post and noticed there was a visual issue that was solved. But the image in the post has not been altered. This makes me think that there is another image we should be looking for...

Comment: @usernameiwantedwasalreadytaken It was discussed [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37482530#37482530)

Comment: What tool are you using to decipher it? Also have you tried 51861 aka EAHFA? If you're wondering where I got that, look at the url of this problem.

Comment: Already tried that. Doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mind explaining for a pleb like me how you got the ID ?

Comment: Sure. Why not. It's his user id. Will add it

Comment: Thank you for combining the answers. more readable now

Answer (score 6):

I am roughly sure you're:

> [Avigrail](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5106/avigrail), but surprisingly none of the clues fit.

Reasons:

> (i) [Searching](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=guy+with+the+girls&user=250062&room=) incesterror's chat history for "guy with the girls", you see it refers to [Wesley C2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21411/wesley-situ). Wesley, in turn, refers that only Avigrail called him that, and it [turns](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=guy+with+the+girls&user=132194&room=) out to be true. (ii) Avigrail had the habit of giving away all his reputation in bounties, and posting three dimensional puzzles, and writing in hilarious way, and Incesterror21 has that too. (iii) Incesterror's [first few chat messages](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/250062/incesterror21?tab=recent&page=26) are related to writing riddles, which is probably to evade suspection, and [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=34062961#34062961) also adds to that. (iv) I'm the beginning of all very very very roughly may mean Avigrail and All, both start with the letter A. Also, very very roughly, there's a V in avigrail too.

Antireasons:

> (i) Avigrail's profile ID doesn't decrypts the vignere. Also, his obituary title does no significant job too. (ii) There's no significant connection with the anagram of incesterror (hint 2) or incesterrorba (hint 2') or incesterror's [profile pic](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=37562528#37562528). (ii) Avigrail is dead already (;) (iii) There was a avigrail's riddle with answer "Easy" (I couldn't find it), but it's probably not significant here.

Answer (score 5):

## Partial

### Following hint 5

> His username becomes `incesterroru` (since `U` is the 21st letter)

Now, following hint 2 (with the help of the observations from @richard-dorkey),

> `incesterroru` is an anagram, which, if solved, becomes `resurrection`

If @richard-dorkey is correct,

> This indicates the ressurrection of the "late" [Avigrail](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5106/avigrail).

But, as observed, this does not decrypt the message. So I guess

> The key is his new username: Avigrail -> incesterror21 -> ?????

### Following hint 1

> Because of [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37482530#37482530) we know that one of the visual clues refers to his profile pic. Looking at the hex values of the picture, the "tongue" has a color #510600, which, again, might refer to Avigrail's user id (5106).

Comment: Nice. So, we have everything now - The anagram, the visual, the think big thing(first letters of all posts). Everything leads to the same person..

Comment: Except we haven't solved the third hint (which I think has to do with the masked picture) and `avigrail` does not decrypt the cipher...

Comment: STINO is the id of [Avigrail's profile picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STINO.png?s=328&g=1). The hex codes of the grey part (E7E8EA) don't prove useful, though.

Comment: Ok. So all it's left is to decrypt the cipher...